# Autocomplete Search bar won't read my values

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to make a search bar for my website to redirect pepole on other pages of my website by selecting values from autocomplete suggestions, but when i select a suggestion (example:"Home") and hit search nothing happends, instead when i write the value (example:"chat") it works just fine and it redirects me to another page, my question is: what im doing wrong and why my autocompleted values are not seen by the searchbar?
Here is the code example for values "chat, Home, youtube"

```
function ouvrirPage() {
        var a = document.getElementById("search").value;

        if (a === "chat") {
            window.open("/index.html");
        }

        if (a === "Home") {
            window.open("/customizedalert.html");
        }

        if (a === "youtube") {
            window.open("https://www.youtube.com/");
        }
    }
```

And here is the entire thing:
https://codepen.io/galusk0149007/pen/LYeXvww

Comment: ouvrirPage() function is called on onChange. So maybe when you autocomplete, the searchBar input value is not changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your IDE : Clicking the search icon will navigate to your urls.

```js
// getting all required elements
const searchWrapper = document.querySelector(".search-input");
const inputBox = searchWrapper.querySelector("input");
const suggBox = searchWrapper.querySelector(".autocom-box");
const icon = searchWrapper.querySelector(".icon");
let linkTag = searchWrapper.querySelector("a");
let webLink;

let suggestions = ['chat','home', 'youtube']
// if user press any key and release
inputBox.onkeyup = (e)=>{
    let userData = e.target.value; //user enetered data
    let emptyArray = [];
    if(userData){
        icon.onclick = ()=>{
            webLink = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${userData}`;
            linkTag.setAttribute("href", webLink);
            linkTag.click();
        }
        emptyArray = suggestions.filter((data)=>{
            //filtering array value and user characters to lowercase and return only those words which are start with user enetered chars
            return data.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(userData.toLocaleLowerCase());
        });
        emptyArray = emptyArray.map((data)=>{
            // passing return data inside li tag
            return data = `<li>${data}</li>`;
        });
        searchWrapper.classList.add("active"); //show autocomplete box
        showSuggestions(emptyArray);
        let allList = suggBox.querySelectorAll("li");
        for (let i = 0; i < allList.length; i++) {
            //adding onclick attribute in all li tag
            allList[i].setAttribute("onclick", "select(this)");
        }
    }else{
        searchWrapper.classList.remove("active"); //hide autocomplete box
    }
}

function select(element){
    let selectData = element.textContent;
    inputBox.value = selectData;
    icon.onclick = ()=>{
        webLink = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${selectData}`;
        linkTag.setAttribute("href", webLink);
        linkTag.click();
    }
    searchWrapper.classList.remove("active");
}

function showSuggestions(list){
    let listData;
    if(!list.length){
        userValue = inputBox.value;
        listData = `<li>${userValue}</li>`;
    }else{
      listData = list.join('');
    }
    suggBox.innerHTML = listData;
}
function ouvrirPage() {
    var a = document.getElementById("search").value;

    if (a === "chat") {
        window.open("/index.html");
    }

    if (a === "Home") {
        window.open("/customizedalert.html");
    }

    if (a === "youtube") {
        window.open("https://www.youtube.com/");
    }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  background: #544b8b;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
::selection{
  color: #fff;
  background: #7c71bd;
}
.wrapper{
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 150px auto;
}
.wrapper .search-input{
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.search-input input{
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 60px 0 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.search-input.active input{
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.search-input .autocom-box{
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  max-height: 280px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.search-input.active .autocom-box{
  padding: 10px 8px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.autocom-box li{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.search-input.active .autocom-box li{
  display: block;
}
.autocom-box li:hover{
  background: #efefef;
}
.search-input .icon{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #644bff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="search-input">
        <a href="" target="_blank" hidden></a>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type to search..">
        <div class="autocom-box">
        </div>
        <div class="icon" onclick="ouvrirPage()"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </body>
```